# Is Google causing problems?

Tags: media

I have been getting the following notice from Google's IP address:

> Unable to generate the derived image located at public://styles/large/public/field/image/imagefield_b9xgKB.jpg

Why does it happens? It started a week ago, and now it happens few times in a day. Sometimes the filename varies.

Comment: Do you have an image with that name? Do you use that image style? Have you checked google's webmaster tool to see why it's trying to index that image? Is this Drupal related?

Answer (score 1):

This is an error saying you have a link to an non-existing resource.

You should use Webmaster Tools to dig deeper, if I remember correctly, it should provide the URL for the page with the bad link.